# MATLAB – Logarithm operator error

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a script in MATLAB that displays Before and After images of a given original image and an image gone through the logarithm operator point transformation. I've tried debugging the program to see what's wrong with it, but for some reason, it isn't running in MATLAB. I keep getting the error on the command line (logarithm-operator is the name of the script):

[image]

Here is the script:

```
a = imread('cells.png');
ad = im2double(a);
x = ad; 

[r, c] = size(ad);
factor = 1;

for i = 1:r 
    for j = 1:c 
        x(i, j) = factor *log(1+ ad(i,j));
    end
end

subplot(1,2,1);imshow(ad);title('Before');

subplot(1,2,2);imshow(x);title('After');
```

Comment: That code does not throw the error you are showing. there is no variable called `logarithm` in that code.

Comment: It does if it's saved in a file named `logorithm-operator.m` and called from the command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matlab script or function names cannot contain a hyphen; only letters, numbers, or underscores are allowed, and must begin with a letter. The hyphen in your script's name confuses Matlab and leads it into thinking that `logarithm` is the name of the function/script it's supposed to be calling.

These are the same requirements as those for variable names. You can have a look at [the documentation for `isvarname`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isvarname.html):

> A valid variable name is a character string of letters, digits, and
>   underscores, totaling not more than `namelengthmax` characters and
>   beginning with a letter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the name of your script from `logarithm-operator` to `logarithm_operator`. Because the *names* of variables, scripts, functions, etc in matlab does not contain the symbol : hyphen  **-**.